# Is it possible to use both of pm2 and forever command for aws node server starting?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am going to stop current aws node server but I don't know which command is used for server starting.
So I can't stop current node server.
If I use forever or pm2 for server starting without stopping current instance , what happens?
Is it possible to use this?
Is old instance stopped after starting new server using pm2 or forever command?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For forever you can use

```
forever list
```

to see if there are any instances running and then use

```
forever stop <instance uid> to stop it
```

You probably will not be able to run the script again since it will try to use the same port as the running instance, but if you wish, you can always run another instance on a different port like:

```
forever start app.js --port=5000
```

So, yes, you can run many instances, but on different ports.

pm2 should be working the same way, I haven't used it though, you should read the help.

Comment: Thanks for your replying.    But current instance was not started using forever or pm2.   I wanna know what happens if I don't stop current instance and start server using forever or pm2.
It it possible?

Comment: If you try to start another instance, as I already answered, it will fail if another instance is already running. The reason: the port the instance runs will not be available and you will end up with an error. That's all, you just will not be able to start it. If it starts however, that means you don't have an instance running. I suggest you use "netstat --pelnut" to see what ports are opened.